# install MongoDB on windows server 2012

Tags: mongodb, azure, windows-server-2012

I am trying to install MongoDB on Windows Azure VM which is running Windows 2012 Server

1. I have mongodb in **C:\Program Files\MongoDB\bin**
2. I have config file at **D:\mongodb\mongod.cfg**

And my config looks like this

```
logpath=d:\mongodb\log\mongod.log
dbpath=d:\mongodb\data\db
port=27018
```

now I want to run mongo db from config file so i go to command prompt and run below command
`c:\Program Files\MongoDB\bin>mongod --config "D:\mongodb\mongod.cfg"` this stays silent on command prompt no further response.

Then I tried `c:\Program Files\MongoDB\bin>mongod --config "D:\mongodb\mongod.cfg" --install` that give me bellow message

**2014-05-02xxxxxx log file "d:mongodb\log\mongod.log" exists; moved to "d:mongodb\log\mongod.log.2014-05-02xxxxx"**

I guess this is just creating a log file for me.

Now if I run `mongod.exe` it give me error saying **dbpath (\data\db\) does not exist**. But in my config file i gave the path as `dbpath=d:\mongodb\data\db`

Changed my config file to YAML

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "e:\\mongodb\\log\\mongod.log"
   quiet: true
   logAppend: true
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27018
storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true
   dbPath: "e:\\mongodb\\data\\db"
```

now I run **mongod --config "C:\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\mongod.cfg"** no response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config file has wrong syntax (it uses [YAML syntax](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/)). Change it to:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "d:\\mongodb\\log\\mongod.log"
net:
  port: 27018
storage:
  dbPath: "d:\\mongodb\\data\\db"
```

Alternatively you can also use `mongod --dbpath "d:\mongodb\data\db"`

Comment: systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "d:\mongodb\log\mongod.log"
   quiet: true
   logAppend: true
storage:
   dbPath:"d:\mongodb\data\db"
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27018  Error: unrecognized escape character \m in line 3

Comment: changed the path to "d:\\mongodb\\log\\mongod.log" now the new error unrecognized option storage

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Production Release (2.6.0)

Comment: I see there was space need dbPath:"d:\ dbPath: "d:\. but now mongod --config "fullpath\mongod.cfg" this doesn't give any response

Comment: which is fine as you are running it obviously in interactive mode. Try to fire up another terminal and connect using `mongo`. You maybe want to install a Windows service after you verified the installation.

Comment: Installed mongo windows server and it is running. opened another cmd prompt. and  ran mongo gives error failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 but I configured 127.0.0.1:27018 in config file.

Comment: then, of course, you need to tell the non-standard port `mongo --port 27018` see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongo/

Comment: okay. that's one step further. should i be able to browse http://localhost:27018 or http://localhost:28018 ? both don't work. I am trying to establish remote connection from a different server